# Apache Marmotta LDPath libraries - Selecting URI fn:content

Tags: java, parsing, rdf, apache-marmotta

I am selecting certain rdf properties using Apache Marmotta LDPath. The documentation (http://marmotta.apache.org/ldpath/language.html) denotes *fn* and *lmf* prefixes are not neccesary explicitly defined.

My code is:

```
@prefix dc : <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> ;
id = . :: xsd:string ;
title = dc:title :: xsd:string ;
file = fn:content(.) :: lmf:text_es ;
```

but I get the next ParseException:

```
Caused by: org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.ParseException: function with URI http://www.newmedialab.at/lmf/functions/1.0/content does not exist 
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.getFunction(LdPathParser.java:213)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.FunctionSelector(LdPathParser.java:852)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.AtomicSelector(LdPathParser.java:686)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.Selector(LdPathParser.java:607)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.Rule(LdPathParser.java:441)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.Program(LdPathParser.java:406)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.parser.LdPathParser.parseProgram(LdPathParser.java:112)
at org.apache.marmotta.ldpath.LDPath.programQuery(LDPath.java:235)
... 47 more
```

### Edit

I'm using the LDPath core Fedora Duraspace 4.5.1. My goal is Solr indexing full text of binary resources, anyway to proceed is valid for me.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it need it, 
it seems subset Apache Marmotta LDPath library does not support complex functions like *fn:*, *lmf*, and others.
For indexing full text of binary resources is necessary to use Apache Tika, for example.